# the meaning of "pretty happening"

Tags: meaning

What does "they're pretty happening" mean in the following sentence?

“These soccer players, they’re pretty happening,” the men’s designer Todd Snyder said. “David Beckham really set the bar. He paved the way for all of this.”

Comment: As I read it, it's synonymous with "hip," "trendy," etc.

Comment: "So hot right now".

Comment: 2. (slang, of a person or product) Trendy, up-to-the-minute. *He is a real happening guy.* http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/happening

Answer (score 0):

[Retro 1960s](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/slang/1960s-slang.html) slang for those who missed it:

> Something that was wonderful would be "outta sight" (as in so great,
>   you just couldn’t take it all in.) If a concert was groovy, it was
>   both outta sight and "**happening**" (that is, wonderful and very
>   up-to-date...

Comment: In your answers, please avoid mentioning other users and what they’ve elsewhere written like you just did. Because that isn’t addressing the Original Posting, it comes off as side-chatter. But this is not a chat or a forum, and that sort of thing doesn’t work well in a Q&A format. That’s because their user names may change, they might resign their accounts, the ephemeral comment you are referencing might very well mysteriously vaporize some day, etc etc etc.

Comment: “Written in the rules”? That isn’t how it works here, and you wouldn’t want that anyway: he who lives by the law, dies by law. If you will not take the word of someone who undertands the system and has tried to kindly explain it to you, then nothing else matters.

Comment: No, I won’t. I am not going to waste my time tracking down where it says that this is a Q&A site not a chat forum, nor what all that implies.  If you have not figured it out yet, then you never will. This is not about “rules”; it’s about intent, reason, logic, and community.

Comment: You have obviously gone to great lengths to find some reference. However, the answer is much closer home http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/happening

Comment: This is indeed not a traditional discussion forum or chat, so personal addresses quite typically do get removed from posts (and it has always been that way on all sites of the network). The reasoning is explained e.g. in [this meta post](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/1123/300), which links to further reading on the Meta meta.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Please indicate example of personal chat in my original response -thank you

Comment: Unfortunately the cited mention of "happening" has vanished from the lines from Retro 1960s quoted in this answer. The text there now reads, "Something that was wonderful would be "outta sight" (as in so great or unbelievable, you just couldn’t take it all in.) ... If a concert was groovy, it was both outta sight and "cool."